# Does trace commutes with Laplacian?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, trace

Suppose $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold and $T$ a $(0,2)-$tensor. Is it true that trace commutes with Laplacian? i.e.
$$\mathsf{tr\ }\Delta T=\Delta \mathsf{tr\ }  T?$$

In my point of view it is true because $\Delta T_{kl}=g^{ij}\nabla_i\nabla_j T_{kl}$  and we know that any trace commutes with covariant derivative (if I am not mistaken in this case/ as Prof. Lee response to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2365939/272127) show the trace should be independent of covariant derivative indices that I think is here.).

So if $\mathsf{tr\ } T=0$ then $\mathsf{tr\ }\Delta  T=0$? e.g. if $\omega$ is a two form then $\mathsf{tr\ }\Delta  \omega=0$?

Comment: Yes, but you should prove it yourself. It's not a good idea to just take our word for it.

Comment: As long as trace commutes with covariant derivative (and it does) this is obvious.

Comment: @Deane: Sorry, Laplacian for functions is just $\Delta=\delta d$. So If $h^i_j$ is a $(1,1)$-tensor then what does second Laplacian means here $\Delta tr h=tr \Delta h$. i.e. it is $\delta d$ or it is $\delta d+d\delta$?

Comment: @Deane: I just figured out that my answer has a small flaw. I think my argument is wrong in this step: $\nabla\mathsf{tr_{12} \nabla} T=\nabla\nabla\mathsf{tr_{12} } T$ because $\mathsf{tr_{12}}$ is depend on the index of $\nabla$ and In this case we can't pass $\nabla$. Am I right?

Comment: No. You can commute covariant differentiation with multiplication by the metric. So $g^{ij}\nabla_i\ldots = \nabla_i(g^{ij}\ldots)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to [this answer of Professor Lee](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2366064/272127), because the second trace is independent from covariant derivative indices so $$\mathsf{tr\ }\Delta T=\mathsf{tr_{12}\ }(\mathsf{tr_{34}\ }\nabla\nabla T)=\mathsf{tr_{34}\ }(\mathsf{tr_{12} }\nabla\nabla T)=\mathsf{tr_{34}\ }(\nabla\mathsf{tr_{12} }\nabla T)=\mathsf{tr_{34}\ }(\nabla\nabla\mathsf{tr_{12} } T)=\Delta \mathsf{tr\ }  T$$
So trace commutes with Laplacian. and if $\mathsf{tr\ }  T=0$ then $\mathsf{tr\ }\Delta  T=0$. like Laplacian of differential 2-forms.